# Unable to load listview in asynctask from database

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to load the items in listview which are queried from DB.
The UI is blank for 2 seconds and then the listviewis shown with all the items. I am unable to figure out the wrong part in my code. 
Below is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

    // Get ListView object from xml
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    dbHandler = new MemoDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

    ListFetchAsyncTask asyncList = new ListFetchAsyncTask();

    asyncList.execute();
```

}

Now Asynctask to load the items

```
class ListFetchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<MemoInfo>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        listView.setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);

    }

    protected List<MemoInfo> doInBackground(String... params) {

        Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getFullListCursor();
        if (cursor != null) {

            if(memoList != null)
            {
                if(!memoList.isEmpty())
                {
                    memoList.clear();
                }
            }
            else
                memoList = new  ArrayList<MemoInfo>();

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                do {

                    // Get version from Cursor
                    String memoText = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text"));


                    String createdDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("createdDate"));

                    Integer id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));

                    MemoInfo memo = new MemoInfo();
                    memo.set_id(id);
                    memo.set_memotext(memoText);
                    memo.set_createdDate(createdDate);
                    memoList.add(memo);

                    // move to next row
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        return memoList;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<MemoInfo> list) {
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no error. But i am not understanding y the UI is blank for 2 secs and then it loads. Listview should be shown first n then items should be added in background i guess

Comment: Since accessing database can be slow. However you shouldn't use the AsyncTask for querying database: try using [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Comment: Your approach is doubtful, use a `CursorAdapter` for your scenario. Analyze your lag, use `TraceView`

Comment: @Skynet: I used CursorAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter. It is working fine. I guess I need not use asynctask to load as it is fast. Please guide me in this.

Comment: You can instead use a [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) or a [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html)

Comment: I am unable to find a good example on CursorLoader without content provider. Please share some good links on this. Thanks